# How can I make DevExpress label ClientVisible using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, devexpress

I have generated a label using DevExpress , How can I make this label ClientVisible using Jquery.
The Id to access the labelo will be $('#lbl_Err_'+ Model.Id)

```
Html.DevExpress().Label(lbl => {
    lbl.Name = string.Format("lbl_Err_{0}", Model.Id);
    lbl.Text = "You must supply a reason`enter code here`n: 10 characters minimum";
    lbl.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = false;
    lbl.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
    lbl.ClientVisible = false;
    lbl.ControlStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

}).Render();
```

Answer (score 0):

use [SetVisible](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientControlBase_SetVisibletopic.aspx) from [Label's client-side API](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientTextBoxMembersTopicAll).

For example:

```
lbl.SetVisible(true);
```

**Reference:**
[How to change Label's text on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q389027)